# ADD not REPLACE a number in a SQL database

Tags: sql, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having issues adding to a previous sum in a Ruby on Rails project using a PostgreSQL database. Basically I need to send a patch request to ADD to the current sum, but instead not REPLACE the current sum.

Everything I'm trying is really complicated, it involves creating new entries for each patch request and aggregating them. Is there a simple way to update a single entry by adding the value rather than replacing it? The frontend is React, I could try doing the math there.

Thanks this has been a real headscratcher and I feel there's a super simple solution.

Comment: In SQL to add a value (delta) we replace the previous one (x) with x+delta.

Comment: `update the_table set the_column = the_column + 42`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How would I do this with a Ruby-on-Rails controller?

Comment: The best way to model this RESTfully (and thus in the controller) really depends on the domain. Try to approach the problem not from the standpoint of "I want to increment a number" but rather what the operation means in terms of creating or updating resources.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to update a single record, you can use the [increment!](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!) method provided by ActiveRecord:

```rb
item = Item.find(1234)
item.increment!('my_column', 5)
```

Rather than reading, adding 5, and saving, Rails will create a SQL statement that will update whatever value was there by 5 (which is very convenient to avoid race conditions):

```
UPDATE 
  "items" 
SET 
  "my_column" = COALESCE("my_column", 0) + 5 
WHERE 
  "tracking_infos"."id" = 1234
```

On the contrary, if you want to update multiple (potentially all) elements, you may need to build the SQL query yourself and ask Rails to execute it for you:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
  "UPDATE items SET my_column = COALESCE(my_column, 0) + 5"
)
```

Keep in mind that this command will increment the value of `my_column` on each record of the table. You may want to include additional `WHERE` conditions to limit the scope of these changes.